# How to enable Windows Hello on stand-alone server

Tags: windows, group-policy

Does anyone know how I can enable Windows Hello facial sign-on a Windows 2019 stand-alone server?

I am the administrator of this stand-alone server, and have installed the Windows Biometric Framework, enabled various Windows Hello for Business group policy settings.

I have installed %windir%\system32\WinBioPlugIns\FaceDriver\HelloFace.inf.

These are my group policy settings:

- Allow the use of biometrics: enabled
- Allows users to log on using biometrics: enabled
- Configure enhanced anti-spoofing: disabled
- Use biometrics: enabled
- Use Windows Hello for Business: enabled
- Use Windows Hello for Business certificates as smart card certificates: disabled
- Use certificate for on-premises authentication: enabled

This stand-alone system does not have any roles installed, besides Storage Services and Hyper-V. There is no Active Directory. I don't see my [deployment scenario](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/) covered.

So far, I'm unable to see any face sign-on, except the following.

I've tested the Logitech Brio webcam on a stand-alone (not joined to any domain) laptop, and on that laptop, face sign-on works.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

[image: Sign-on options]

Comment: What cameras are presented on the server in device manager?

Comment: Updated post to add Logitech Brio webcam. That's the only one on the server.

Comment: Is the device present in device manager? Does it function?

Comment: Yes, the webcam is present in Device Manager and it functions with Google's Chrome when I start meet.google.com.

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, full camera functionality required a USB 3.0 port. Is your camera plugged into a USB 3.0 port on the server?

You may also need to *disable* the Windows Hello *for Business* setting that was enabled in your GPO. As you've probably seen in the [deployment requirements for Windows Hello for Business](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-identity-verification#on-premises-deployments), a standalone server wouldn't work with it enabled: WHfB requires Active Directory, ADCS, ADFS, etc to be configured. "Windows Hello" *might* still work for you, as long as the server SKU you're running doesn't automatically infer "Windows Hello *for Business*" whenever Windows Hello settings are invoked.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple USB 3 ports, and it's tested in the sense that on the same server where it didn't work, I ran a VM (Windows 10) that used the webcam and Windows Hello worked in the VM, without even changing the USB port where the webcam was plugged in.

Comment: Curiously, I just tested the webcam with USB 2 port as well on my VM running on the server. In the VM, Windows Hello worked as well. So it doesn't appear that USB 2 or 3 makes a difference.

Comment: Good, that may have been specific to the camera that I tested with.